# Special Characters in Expression Engine Template Variables

Tags: expressionengine

I'm not holding my breath for this one, but was curious if someone had a more elegant solution to displaying a date format `%d %M, '%Y` (13 May, '13) in a single statement using Expression Engine's template variables.

My solution: {entry_date format="%d %M, "}'{entry_date format="%y"}

I'm wondering if there's a way of escaping the single quote...  Thanks for sharing your $.02 if you have them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the HTML entity:
`{entry_date format="%d %M &#39;%y"}`